# /opt/mssql/bin/sqlservr: error while loading shared libraries: libssl.so.1.1: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32

Tags: apt, ssl, mssql

I am trying to install [mssql-server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/quickstart-install-connect-ubuntu?view=sql-server-ver16&tabs=ubuntu2204#install) and when running the setup I get the following error at the end:

```
/opt/mssql/bin/sqlservr: error while loading shared libraries: libssl.so.1.1: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32
```

This comes after setting up a smlink to libssl.so.1.1 as it would otherwise not be found:

```
hutber@hutber-xps:/usr/lib$ sudo ln -s /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.1 libssl.so.1.1
hutber@hutber-xps:/usr/lib$ ls -l libssl*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 33 Feb 26 14:30 libssl.so.1.1 -> /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.1
```

I am running 22.04 with a fresh install.

It runs the setup after having successfully installed:
Enter Option 1-11: 1
Enter the SQL Server system administrator password:
Confirm the SQL Server system administrator password:
Configuring SQL Server...

```
/opt/mssql/bin/sqlservr: error while loading shared libraries: libssl.so.1.1: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32
Created symlink /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/mssql-server.service → /lib/systemd/system/mssql-server.service.
Setup has completed successfully. SQL Server is now starting.
```

So I believe I need to fix the libssl issue to be able to finish setup.

Comment: looks to me you installed 32-bit software and need 64-bit. "libssl.so.1.1: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32" Or install support for 32 if that is still an option.

Comment: Are you sure you followed the correct tab (for 22.04 not 20.04)? Ubuntu 22.04 uses ssl3 and afaik no longer provides ssl1.x libraries, so a *supported* version of mssql should either use libssl.so.3 or provide its own 64-bit 1.x versions of libssl / libcrpto.

Comment: I think you might be right @steeldriver I made sure I was following 22.04 with :`Get:1 https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/22.04/mssql-server-2022 jammy/main amd64 mssql-server amd64 16.0.4105.2-2 [267 MB]
` and now everything runs correctly